In the context of Hardware Security and Cryptography, how do I calculate the Algebraic Normal Form for sboxes
In our hardware security exercise, I am trying to calculate the ANF function manually (Sboxes) for the given table:

And I came up with the result as:

I thought I was calculating it correctly using the XOR function but then dont remember when did our professor applied the AND function for it. So right now I am not even sure if I am doing it correctly. Anyone care to explain when to use the xor function and when to use the AND function in the table?

no. because we are solving the a's calculation from the given table of x's and a given y.

but that answer does use the x's to obtain the y. what exactly don't you understand? the mobius matrix form illustrates it as a linear map modulo 2.
